# I'm getting a "ModuleNotFound" error for a user defined file that is very much in the same path

Tags: python, path

So I'm trying to import modules from a user-created file called Models.py, and I've triple-checked that it's in the same folder as the file I'm running, but I keep getting this error:

```
runcell(0, 'C:/Users/Neha/Downloads/RIS-main/RIS-main/RIS.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\Downloads\RIS-main\RIS-main\RIS.py:5 in <module>
    from Models import GaussianPolicy, EnsembleCritic, LaplacePolicy, Encoder

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Models'
```

I've tried phrasing it as Modules.py in the command but I get the same error. Does anyone know what's going on? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: add in the import line you're running which generates this error. Have you checked there aren't any blank spaces or typos in the file name?

Comment: It's there in the error message I posted above. It's just "Models". I've checked for spaces and typos, even tried moving everything into a different file, nothing seems to work :(